# getElementsByTagName how to get xml data

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I'm using this scipt to make a browser compatible xml reader.

However I never used one of these badboys, and I have no idea how can I get the data from the object tag below.

I need to print it int this part: `document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);`

But here is the full code (with the object xml tag.

```
    <script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","myxml.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 


var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("property");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write("<table border='1'>");
  document.write("<tr><td>Utolsomod</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("EPOLeafNode.LastUpdate")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td></tr><tr><td>Song</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td></tr>");
  document.write("</table>");
  document.write("<br/>");
  }

</script>



<object index="20">
<property name="name1">*somedate*</property>
<property name="name2">*somename*</property>
<property name="name3">*someip*</property>
</object>
```

Comment: You might want to read up on [Xpath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath) which is made to parse XML. Might not be exactly what you want but it could provide clues.

Comment: I understand the main conept of them, but I have no idea with this kind of xml, so unfortunately that did not help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out as: `document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("property")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);`

Thank you guys for helping. :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
document.write(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("EPOLeafNode.LastUpdate")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
XmlDocument axmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
axmlDoc.Load(myxml.xml);
XmlNodeList prop = axmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("property");
prop[i].InnerText
```